# According to Catholicism, what are angels and what are they for?

Tags: catholicism, angels

I am a Roman Catholic and believe in angels, so I would like to know more about angels and their characteristics. It would be very useful if answers are related with biblical comparisons.

- What is an angel?
- What is their purpose?
- Where they will be?
- How many are there?
- What do they look like (a spirit/physical body)?

Comment: You may wish to start here [Angels | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01476d.htm).

Comment: This is too broad - it's got too many subpoints. What research have you done before now?

Comment: Read St. Thomas Aquinas's [Treatise on the Angels](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/summa/FP.html#TOC03) from his _Summa Theologica_.

Answer (score 5):

A thorough answer would occupy volumes as this article shows: [Angels | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01476d.htm). The following serves as an introduction

A good summary and introduction is found in the [Catechism of the catholic Church 328-336](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s2c1p5.htm#327). In part (sans footnotes)

> **I. THE ANGELS**
>
> **The existence of angels - a truth of faith**
>
> **328** The existence of the spiritual, non-corporeal beings that Sacred Scripture usually calls "angels" is a truth of faith. The
>   witness of Scripture is as clear as the unanimity of Tradition.
>
> **Who are they?**
>
> **329** St. Augustine says: "'Angel' is the name of their office, not of their nature. If you seek the name of their nature, it is 'spirit';
>   if you seek the name of their office, it is 'angel': from what they
>   are, 'spirit', from what they do, 'angel.'" With their whole beings
>   the angels are servants and messengers of God. Because they "always
>   behold the face of my Father who is in heaven" they are the "mighty
>   ones who do his word, hearkening to the voice of his word".
>
> **330** As purely spiritual creatures angels have intelligence and will: they are personal and immortal creatures, surpassing in
>   perfection all visible creatures, as the splendor of their glory bears
>   witness.

This answers but two of your bullet points

- *Where they will be?* I do not understand. Their abode is the heavens but they go wherever God's want them to accomplish his will which is done in heaven.
- *How many are there?*

I quote from the New Advent article

> **The number of angels**
>
> The number of the angels is frequently stated as prodigious (Daniel
>   7:10; Apocalypse 5:11; Psalm 67:18; Matthew 26:53). From the use of
>   the word host (sabaoth) as a synonym for the heavenly army it is hard
>   to resist the impression that the term "Lord of Hosts" refers to God's
>   Supreme command of the angelic multitude (cf. Deuteronomy 33:2; 32:43;
>   Septuagint). The Fathers see a reference to the relative numbers of
>   men and angels in the parable of the hundred sheep (Luke 15:1-3),
>   though this may seem fanciful. The Scholastics, again, following the
>   treatise "De Coelesti Hierarchia" of St. Denis, regard the
>   preponderance of numbers as a necessary perfection of the angelic host
>   (cf. St. Thomas, Summa Theologica I:1:3).